# WPA_supplicant authentication implementation

Tags: wpa-supplicant

I need help from someone that have some experience in playing with wpa_supplicant code.

What i understand is that wpa_supplicant dose everything in order for a supplicant to connect to an AP (if that what you what). Hence the steps are as:

1. Scan
2. Get scan results
3. AUTH
4. ASSOC
5. 4-hand shake
6. data exchange

As i understand this then the first 4 steps are only managed by wpa_supplicant. That is, wpa_supplicant simply calls the under laying driver to perform these steps and after the main event loop receives the EVENT_ASSOC msg. it starts the 4-handshake.

For my part, it is fine with the first two steps are carried out at the driver, ie., wpa_supplicant send a scan req, the driver perform the scan and feed the scan results.

My question is, is it correct that wpa_supplicant cannot generate the necessary packet and use, e.g., layer 2 (rawsocket) to send authentication request to the AP ? and followed by an associate request ?... shall one simply provides these as a handle from the driver layer ?

as i can see from the code in wpa_supplicant.c 
(void wpa_supplicant_associate(struct wpa_supplicant *wpa_s,
                  struct wpa_bss *bss, struct wpa_ssid *ssid))

that this function calls a function pointer to the selected driver eg. ".associate = wpa_driver_nl80211_associate" and here the driver then send this down to the udnerlaying nl80211 driver code ? .... so wpa_supplicant can not generate these packet by it self ?

I hope that this make any sens, if not please ask :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your understanding is correct. To send auth/assoc req, the wpa_supplicant should construct the corresponding NL80211 commands in following different scenarios:
a) in case the SME is maintained in wpa_supplicant

- NL80211_CMD_AUTHENTICATE
- NL80211_CMD_ASSOCIATE

b) in case the SME is maintained by driver

- NL80211_CMD_CONNECT

And these commands will trigger the corresponding cfg80211_ops hooks (.auth, .assoc, .connect) registered by the wifi driver to be called to construct the frames and then send out the frames.